# How does the heart rate change during REM and non-REM stages?

Tags: sleep-cycles, heart-rate, heartbeat, rapid-eye-movement-rem

I read different references and I understand that the average heart rate during sleep **decreases** by some beats per minute. The heart rate is **slower** in non-REM stage than REM but I found no measurements or ranges related to the heart rate variation during these two stages. If we consider a healthy group of people, does the heart rate during REM and non-REM change within a specific range?  Is it possible to detect the REM stage by only tracking the heart rate (by wearable watches)?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Just data, or an explanation. You question title doesn't really have much in common with the question asked in the body apart from being about REM.